# MySQL Database Structure for Employee Position Database

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, am working with a Human Resource Management application.

Positions (like trainer, deputy manager, manager, etc) are filled up based on their service.

There is a list of all employees, the one with highest service on any given date occupies the top-most position.

The number of key positions are fixed. Based on the employee's position in the list, his probable position will be displayed.

The positions are like:

- *(Position - Number of Posts)*
- Director - 1
- Manager - 3
- Dy. Manager - 5
- Trainer - 10

Now, in the list of employees populated based on their experience, the first in the list will be the Director, next three will be Managers, following 5 employees will be Dy. Managers and next ten would be Trainers.

I want to design a database table for storing the positions and associated numbers. There may be possibility that new positions will be added and also, the number of positions may change with time. Example, if the number of Director posts are increased to two from one, it should be edited. As soon as the number of Director posts are edited, the first two employees in the list will be designated as probable Directors. The same logic holds good to all the other positions too.

Am not sure what should be the database structure for such a table. After done, I should be able to query the table using php for probable position of any given employee based on his rank in the employees list.

Example, if an employee is in rank 5, I should be able to query the table and get the probable position. In this case, rank 5 will be Dy. Manager.

Hope I have made my requirement clear. Please help me in designing a database table for this purpose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Employees
=========
name | Boss
rank | 1
doj  | 2010-01-01
```

"Select name from Employees order by rank, doj"

doj = date of joining

Is that what you mean?

`rank` could join to another table, where you store the readable rank title in order to generate title, name, etc

Answer (score 0):

The existing employee database table consists of:

```
Employees
=========
name | Mark
doj  | 2010-01-01
wrk  | yes
```

"Select name from Employees where wrk=yes order by doj"

(this will remove employees in database who has left the company, with status wrk = no)

Lets say this will generate the results something like this:

```
Mark | 2010-01-01
Steve | 2010-02-01
Jack | 2010-04-01
Rick | 2010-09-01
David | 2010-12-01
```

Now, when I fetch the results and assign position based on their seniority (assuming positions manager=1, dy. manager=3, trainer=1) the result would be:

```
Rank | Name | Doj | Designation
1 | Mark | 2010-01-01 | Manager
2 | Steve | 2010-02-01 | Dy. Manager
3 | Jack | 2010-04-01 | Dy. Manager
4 | Rick | 2010-09-01 | Dy. Manager
5 | David | 2010-12-01 | Trainer
```

After some days, lets assume Jack quits the company (his wrk status will be no). So, the fetched results would look:

```
Rank | Name | Doj | Designation
1 | Mark | 2010-01-01 | Manager
2 | Steve | 2010-02-01 | Dy. Manager
3 | Rick | 2010-09-01 | Dy. Manager
4 | David | 2010-12-01 | Dy. Manager
```

As Jack quits, David gets promoted. The rank is just the serial number generated based on the number of rows fetched, auto increment.

Now, I wanted to create a table for the designation and number of positions, so that based on the rank, it fetches the designation.